# How to make widget to occupy all the available space in Gtk.HBox

Tags: gtk, gtk#, gtk2

I am implementing a custom Gtk# widget which is based on `Gtk.EventBox`. When I am inserting it into the `HBox` or `VBox` it occupies the exact size that is returned by `OnSizeRequested` method.

How can I make my widget to occupy all the space given to it by the parent box, window or the widget? Just like HBox does.

Answer (score 2):

There is a slight different between the *preferred* way to do packing in GTK+2 vs GTK+3. With GTK+ you would typically use `expand` and `fill` properties of a `GtkBox` to control how space is allocated. With GTK+3 they are suggesting the user of `vertical-expand`, `horizontal-expand`, `vertical-fill`, `horizontal-fill`.

A good way to understand how packing works is to play with the fill and expand properties with  [Glade](http://glade.gnome.org/) so you can see the effects in real time. An old tutorial (slightly out of date) shows some screenshots of different packing properties: [How_Packing_Effects_the_Layout](http://www.micahcarrick.com/gtk-glade-tutorial-part-1.html#How_Packing_Effects_the_Layout)

As you are developing a widget it is more likely that *users* of your widget will determine how it should be packed in a larger UI. However, if you're widget is a composite widget (built from other widgets) then you will need to pack the other widgets properly.

Answer (score 0):

PackStart and PackEnd have a fill parameter to specify items that should expand to fill the box.  You probably want PackStart(widget, true, true, 0);